# How to identify SpriteKit node by id or number?

Tags: ios, ios7, sprite-kit

In my scene world I have "blocks" with category ("blockCategory") and an object colliding with these blocks. I wish to identify which *specific* block (using block index) the object has touched.

The only way I found is giving a name to the blocks, but I already use :

```
        block.name = blockOfType ..
```

In order to identify the block types. I also found I could use node.userData to place custom data, but it seems to be with a large overhead to use dictionary. Is there a simpler way?

Comment: Doesn't seem like too big an overhead to me.  Do you know how much additional memory it would consume?

Comment: Since I have many blocks, accessing the dictionary and updating is super fast.

Comment: You could also add all your blocks to an NSMutableArray and then go through the array using the isEqual: method to find the right one. This however, would cause CPU overhead as compared to memory overhead while using the userData property.

Comment: How are you testing for collisions?

Comment: You could also subclass SKSpriteNode and add another property to it. It could be anything, an integer, bool or string. This will give you another parameter for comparison.

Comment: I have used the NSDictionary option:

block.userData = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",index] forKey:@"index"];

And then accessing the index: 

NSInteger currentBlockIndex = [[secondBody.node.userData objectForKey:@"index"] integerValue];
            
It seems to work OK, I just thought there is a simpler way.